# how to get access token from bitly using password and username?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, token

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/oauth/access_token',

            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            dataType: 'json',

            data: { Authorization: "Basic " + btoa('myusername' + ":" + 'mypassword@123') },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Cannot get data");
            }
        });
```

I am trying to get access token from bitly api by providing username and password but it is showing invalid_client_authorization error. Does any one have idea on the same?

Bitly documentation : http://dev.bitly.com/authentication.html#resource_owner_credentials

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating your username with your authorization header.

Your authorization and content-type should go in the headers object.

There is no 'type' property on jquery ajax method, you probably meant 'method'.

Also, you can't send both dataType:'json' and set the content-type to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/oauth/access_token',

        methdo: 'POST',
        contentType: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + [INSERT YOUR HASH HERE],
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
        data: { $.serialize({
            username: YOURUSERNAME,
            password: YOURPASSWORD
        })},
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Cannot get data");
        }
    });
```

This should do it

Comment: Hi, its not working also with the code you provided. Also, its giving error on $.serialize

Comment: This code sample does not work, but it does contain some key points. See my answer for a concise and working sample.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed @goncalomarques answer:

- Removed top level "contentType" and "dataType"
- Removed data object (otherwise username and password is sent as clear text, in addition to the hashed username and password in the header)
- renamed "methdo" to "method"
- Explicitly used btoa() to get Base 64 encoded hash (be aware, does not work in older IE versions)

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/oauth/access_token',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(YOURUSERNAME + ':' + YOURPASSWORD),
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  success: function(result) {
    console.log("success");
    console.log(result);
  },
  error: function(response) {
    console.log("Cannot get data");
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

---

Note:
I have this example working, but was unable to get it working with the built-in Stackoverflow editor ("Run snippet") due to cross origin exceptions.